# How to have less channels in vse standard view

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In `VSE`, 8 channels are displayed in the default view.
So if I insert one or two strips in separate tracks, press TAB to clear the spaces, I usually get by for small edits with 2 tracks that I use alternately, plus a third, at most a fourth for effect strips, and maybe even an audio track.

As I said, this is not about large projects that quickly require a lot more tracks, but small edits that I like to try out quickly on the side.
If I now select all strips and press the `pos1` / `home` button, then Blender conveniently zooms in all editors to an optimal position that shows exactly everything.
But in VSE this view is always at least 8 Channels high and looks like this:
[image]

I like the thumbnail preview strips and want to be able to see them well.

With `strg` + `mmb` I can zoom by hand, but I don't know a method to limit this to the vertical, so that I regularly shift in width.
But i would like to have it more like this, to have better use of the vertical space for the thumbnail preview:

[image]

Is it somehow possible to have the standard view with less than 8 Channels, so that the `home` button zooms in accordingly?

Comment: Now that you ask, this might be a good question - maybe not for this site because I'm wondering if there is a bug that needs to be reported. I know how you can have Blender start with only e.g. 4 channels, but I don't find any setting for how many channels should be shown when pressing _Home_. But: in the _View_ menu of the _Sequencer Editor_ there is the (by default enabled) option _Limit View to Contents_. The mouseover info and the Blender Reference Manual explain: "Limit the timeline height to the maximum used channel slot." However, it doesn't do that or I misunderstand the given info.

Comment: Sounds interesting. So maybe its a bug.
Anyhow, you also mentioned " I know how you can have Blender start with only e.g. 4 channels". Now i didn't find  this setting, where do i find it?

Comment: That's not a setting. When you startup Blender with the general default layout, go to the _Video Editing_ workspace in the top menu, change the vertical scale of the sequencer, go back to the default workspace called _Layout_, then go to _File_ > _Defaults_ > _Save Startup File_ and after clicking confirm again that you want to _Save Startup File_. Next time you open Blender, switching to the _Video Editing_ workspace should open with 4 channels (at least it does in my Blender). But _Home_ unfortunately takes you back to 8 channels. Saving the startup file allows you to change multiple things.